# Value can be moved even if passed by value

Tags: c++

In the following program, how is it possible for the move to complete if the parameter was passed by value?

Both constructor signatures; `MyContainer(Myclass&& myclass)` and `MyContainer(Myclass myclass)` work equally well, but `Myclass` only has a move constructor, the rest are deleted.

```
#include <iostream>

class Myclass {
public:
    Myclass(int value) : value{value} {std::cout << "Constructed with value " << value << "\n";}
    Myclass(Myclass&& other) : value{other.value}
    {
        other.value = 0;
        std::cout << "Move constructed with value " << value << "\n";
    }
    Myclass(const Myclass& other) = delete;
    Myclass& operator=(const Myclass& other) = delete;
    Myclass& operator=(Myclass&& other) = delete;
    ~Myclass() {std::cout << "Destructed with value " << value << "\n";}
private:
    int value;
};

class MyContainer {
public:
    //MyContainer(Myclass&& myclass) : myclass{std::move(myclass)} { } // Shouldn't this be the constructor definition?
      MyContainer(Myclass   myclass) : myclass{std::move(myclass)} { } // this also works, why?
private:
    Myclass myclass;
};

int main()
{
    Myclass myclass{5};
    MyContainer mycontainer{std::move(myclass)};

    return 0;
}
```

When the constructor is called I do use `std::move`, but how does the compiler 'remember' that it was moved if the parameter was `Myclass` and not `Myclass&&`?

Comment: The argument object is move-constructed from the initializing expression.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see now. If I use `MyContainer(Myclass&& myclass)` it doesn't move it as many times.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why does the overload resolution not find the deleted (non-move) constructor and then produce an error during compilation?

Comment: Why should it? The rvalue constructor is a better match (not requiring const conversion).

Comment: @KerrekSB Fair enough. :) Thanks for the answers. I think I get it. When the constructor is called the parameters (passed by value) are constructed and the `std::move` makes the move constructor a good match. Finally the second `std::move` to initialize the class member makes the same determination. With `Myclass&& myclass` the parameter does not have to be constructed so no constructors are considered. Only the last one for the class member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `MyContainer mycontainer{std::move(myclass)};`, we have to enumerate all the viable constructors of `MyContainer` that can be called with an xvalue of type `Myclass`. `MyContainer` has a single relevant constructor which takes an argument of type `Myclass`. To see if that constructor is viable, we effectively perform overload resolution again on constructing a `Myclass` with an xvalue of type `Myclass`. That gives us three constructors:

```
Myclass(int );                     // not viable: no conversion from `Myclass` to `int`
Myclass(Myclass&& );               // viable
Myclass(const Myclass& ) = delete; // viable
```

The move constructor is viable because you can bind an rvalue reference to an xvalue. The copy constructor is viable because you can bind a const lvalue reference to anything. One of the tiebreakers in overload resolution is picking the *least* *cv*-qualified reference. The move constructor is an rvalue reference to `Myclass`. The copy constructor is an lvalue reference to `Myclass const` - that is more cv-qualified, hence it is less prefered. Thus, we select the move constructor. This constructor is not deleted, so that call is well-formed.

The important part here is that we're constructing with an *xvalue* of type `Myclass` (that's what `std::move()` does - it's a cast to xvalue). If we were constructing with an lvalue (i.e. simply `MyContainer mycontainer(myclass)`) then only the copy constructor would be viable, but it's explicitly deleted so the entire expression is ill-formed.

> how does the compiler 'remember' that it was moved if the parameter was `Myclass` and not `Myclass&&`?

There's no remembering. In both cases, we're trying to initialize the argument in the constructor from an xvalue of type `Myclass`. In the former case, that involves invoking the move constructor of `Myclass`. In the latter case, that's a direct reference binding.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases you are casting your lvalue `myclass` to an rvalue reference.

The return type of `std::move` is an rvalue reference, so by definition, the `std::move` expression is an rvalue - and as such, can bind to the rvalue reference parameter of the move constructor of `MyClass`.

The `std::move` instruction can be interpreted as 'I'm done with this variable, it can now be moved'. Note that this is the case irrespective of what the type of the variable being passed to `std::move` is - it works just as well with normal variables, lvalue reference and rvalue references.

Answer (score 2):

> how is it possible for the move to complete if the parameter was passed by value?

Regular value (argument) variables can be copy-initialized by move.

So, with the value constructor, the argument is copy-initialized by moving from the passed value, and then the member is copy-initialized by moving from the argument.

With the rvalue reference constructor, the argument reference is bound to the passed value, and the member is copy-initialized by moving from the referenced value.

> how does the compiler 'remember' that it was moved if the parameter was `Myclass` and not `Myclass&&`?

The compiler does not need to 'remember' whether an object has been moved from or not (or whether it was constructed by move or otherwise).